# How to get the height of a div after first photo loaded

Tags: jquery, css

I'm creating a web site of image gallery.

First i get the screen dimensions to adapt the maximum height of the image (heightScreen - 100).
Then i calculate the proportional width.
I center horizontally the image with text-align : center;
and vertically with an empty span display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;

This does work correctly.

Then i would like to add legend just below the frame containing the image, for that i use a div with position: relative; wich i retrieve (heightScreen - heightFrame) / 2 and here there is a problem..

I can't get the frame dimensions for the first loaded image, while it s work fine for the others (images)

When my browser take full screen dimensions, that work fine, and that work fine while the screen width is superior at the image width.

To be more precise, i load an image in a frame wich i apply 
height: adaptedHeight, max-width: proportionalWidth BUT the image has itself max-width: 100%, height of the frame doesnt equal adaptedHeight but an inferior value if the screen width is inferior at the proportionalWidth of the image.

To view the problem, please put your browser with an inferior width than images width. You can also view that the problem is just for the first image loaded, 
moreover, after the first image is loaded, $ ( window ).resize(function() {}); replace fine the legend where it must be.

Here's the code:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Test</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <button id="buttonTest" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>

  <div id="content">
    <div id="modal_photo" class="modal fade">
      <span class="span_cadre_photo"></span><!-- 
   --><div id="cadre_photo">
        <img src="">
        <a id="bouton_precedent" class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a id="bouton_suivant" class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="legende_photo">
        <div>
          <h4></h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- id="content" -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="Js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.css

```css
html,body, h4
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body
{
  height: 100%;
}

#content
{
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#modal_photo
{
  height: 100%;
}

.span_cadre_photo
{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

#cadre_photo
{
  background: white;
  position: relative; /* pour que les spans restent dans le cadre */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img
{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#legende_photo
{
  position: relative;
}

#legende_photo div
{
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

test.js

```js
var largeurEcran, hauteurEcran, photoSelectionnee, nombrePhotos;

$( document ).ready (function() {

  getDimensionEcran();

  $ ( window ).resize(function() {
    var hauteurCadre, positionTopLegende;
    hauteurCadre = $( '#cadre_photo' ).height();

    // alert("$ ( window ).resize():  hauteurCadre : " + hauteurCadre);
    // alert("hauteurEcran : " + hauteurEcran);
    // alert("largeurEcran : " + largeurEcran);

    positionTopLegende = ((hauteurEcran - hauteurCadre) / 2);
    // alert("positionTopLegende : " + positionTopLegende);

    $( '#legende_photo' ).css({
      'top': - positionTopLegende
    });
  });

  //Clique sur une photo
  $( '#buttonTest' ).on ('click', function() {
    photoSelectionnee = 1;
    nombrePhotos = 4;

    // alert("largeurEcran : " + largeurEcran);
    // alert("hauteurEcran : " + hauteurEcran);

    afficherModal();
  });

  //Clique sur le bouton précédent du modal
  $( '#bouton_precedent' ).click(function() {
    photoSelectionnee -= 1;
    afficherModal();
  });

  //Clique sur le bouton suivant du modal
  $( '#bouton_suivant' ).click(function() {
    photoSelectionnee += 1;
    afficherModal();
  });

  // A l'apparition du modal
  $( '#modal_photo' ).on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    // alert("on show.bs.modal");
    // var hauteurCadre = $( '#cadre_photo' ).height();
    // var largeurCadre = $( '#cadre_photo' ).width();
    // alert("on show.bs.modal hauteurCadre : " + hauteurCadre);
    // alert("on show.bs.modal largeurCadre : " + largeurCadre);
  });

  // A la fin de l'apparition du modal
  $( '#modal_photo' ).on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    alert("on shown.bs.modal");
    // var hauteurCadre = $( '#cadre_photo' ).height();
    // var largeurCadre = $( '#cadre_photo' ).width();
    // alert("on shown.bs.modal hauteurCadre : " + hauteurCadre);
    // alert("on shown.bs.modal largeurCadre : " + largeurCadre);
  });
});

// $( window ).load(function() {

// });

function getDimensionEcran()
{
  largeurEcran = $(window).width();
  hauteurEcran = $(window).height();
}

function afficherModal()
{
  // alert("afficherModal()");
  // alert("photoSelectionnee : " + photoSelectionnee);
  // alert("nombrePhotos : " + nombrePhotos);

  var cheminImage, legende;

  cheminImage = 'Img/';
  // legende = 'test de legende';
  legende = 'test de legende legende legende legende legende legende legende legende legende legende legende legende legende legende legende';

  if (photoSelectionnee == 0)
  {
    photoSelectionnee = nombrePhotos;
  }
  else if (photoSelectionnee == nombrePhotos + 1)
  {
    photoSelectionnee = 1;
  }

  var hauteurPhoto, largeurPhoto, hauteurAdaptee, largeurProportionelle, hauteurCadre, positionTopLegende;

  $( '#modal_photo img' ).load(function() {


    hauteurPhoto = this.height;
    largeurPhoto = this.width;

    hauteurAdaptee = hauteurEcran - 100;
    // largeurProportionelle = Math.floor((largeurPhoto * hauteurAdaptee) / hauteurPhoto);
    largeurProportionelle = (largeurPhoto * hauteurAdaptee) / hauteurPhoto;

    positionTopLegende = (hauteurEcran - hauteurAdaptee) / 2;
    hauteurCadre = $( '#cadre_photo' ).height();

    if (hauteurCadre > 0)
    {
      positionTopLegende = ((hauteurEcran - hauteurCadre) / 2);
    }

    // alert("hauteurEcran : " + hauteurEcran);
    // alert("largeurEcran : " + largeurEcran);
    // alert("hauteurPhoto : " + hauteurPhoto);
    // alert("largeurPhoto : " + largeurPhoto);
    // alert("hauteurAdaptee : " + hauteurAdaptee);
    // alert("largeurProportionelle : " + largeurProportionelle);
    // alert("hauteurCadre : " + hauteurCadre);
    // alert("positionTopLegende : " + positionTopLegende);

    $( '#cadre_photo' ).css({
      'heigth': hauteurAdaptee,
      'max-width': largeurProportionelle
    });

    $( '#legende_photo' ).css({
      'top': - positionTopLegende
    });

    $( '#legende_photo  div' ).css({
      'width': largeurProportionelle
    });
  });

  $( '#modal_photo img' ).attr('src', cheminImage + photoSelectionnee + '.jpg');

  $( '#modal_photo h4' ).empty();
  $( '#modal_photo h4' ).append(legende);

  $( '#modal_photo' ).modal('show');
}
```

Comment: please add jsfiddle for that. For people it will be easier to help you if there is one.

Comment: ok, i ll try but i dont know where to put images to try

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the solution.

i added  class modal-dialog in the div

`<div id="cadre_photo">`

like this `<div id="cadre_photo" class="modal-dialog">`

For the event on shown.bs modal can be fire, and i do the same think that i did on the rezise window event :

```
$( '#modal_photo' ).on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  var hauteurCadre, positionTopLegende;

  hauteurCadre = $( '#cadre_photo' ).height();
  positionTopLegende = ((hauteurEcran - hauteurCadre) / 2);

  $( '#legende_photo' ).css({
    'top': - positionTopLegende
  });
});
```

Comment: i hope that will help :)